# Getting PHP mail() to show sender like it's sent through Outlook

Tags: php, r, email, outlook

I'm using the mail function to send some mails to specific users from a intranetsite.

It is working, but I want to finetune it if possible. When I set in yyy@domain.com as from address, in Outlook it doesn't show up as a normal mail sent through Outlook from the same sender. It just shows the sender mail, and is doesn't Group the mail with those sent from Outlook. It like is doesn't make the connection between the intranet mail and our Exchange.

Is it somehow possible to get the mail function to show the from address, completely like the mail was sent from Outlook?

---

***Update***

Formatting the sender as

```
`$headers = "From: MyName <MyEmail>" . "\r\n";`
```

didn't make it work 100% as I liked it to do. 
You can see an example off what I'm seeking here: [Picture](http://i43.tinypic.com/2m4rs7k.jpg)

The left part, maked with the mail function, is missing some information about the sender. It is like it doesn't get linked to a AD user. Like the part on the right, where all AD information i visible. Is it somehow possible from PHP to get the sender to be linked with the corresponding user in the AD?

Comment: I know it's not easy to understand, it's not easy for me to describe. But I found the solution my self, the from part should look like this: $headers = "From: MyName <MyEmail>" . "\r\n";
Now I just have to figure out how to find a users full name from his initials through LDAP. Any good links out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

the fourth parameter `$additional_headers` is important. Valid parameters that you should use are: "From:", "Reply-To:" and "X-Mailer:"

[you can see a good example at the php website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) - example #2

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but the best way to replicate a certain mail client's behavior is:

1, send an email from outlook to a gmail address
2, go to gmail and open the mail
3, in the right hand dropdown select "Show original"

In that plain text file you will see the headers sent by Outlook. Try to replicate those headers in your php